# xforms mindate on a date-picker

Tags: xforms, mindate

Could someone please tell me the correct syntax for adding a minimum date/time to the date picker in a datetime field.
This works

```
<fr:date mindate="2012-05-05" ref="mydate">
```

this does not

```
<fr:date mindate="current-date()" ref="mydate">
```

thank you

Comment: fr:date is available from which version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use an attribute for `mindate` or `maxdate` in the [`fr:date`](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components#TOC-Date) component if the value is static. If the value is determined by an XPath expression, you need to use a nested element with the `ref` attribute. So the following should do the trick:

```
<fr:date ref="mydate">
    <fr:mindate ref="current-date()"/>
</fr:date>
```

Comment: @avernet: fr:date is available from which version?